# Problems in connecting Datastax Ops Center with agents

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

we are using Datastax Enterprize edition. We are running a 2 node cluster, and can view the load avgs, storage and other stats of our nodes in Ops center easily. However, when we click on **Agents**, under the heading **Nodes**, we get the message:

```
The DataStax Enterprise storage cluster appears to be configured correctly but still shows errors.
```

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the opscenter.log or agent.logs?

Comment: I am working with Ankush. After restarting of node we are getting error.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909797/opscenter-not-getting-data-after-restart-of-server