# OpsCenter not getting data after restart of server

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

we are using Datastax Enterprize edition. We are running a 2 node cluster. We get the message: After restarting of OpsCentre node getting below error.

```
 2017-03-20 14:49:45,819 [opscenterd] ERROR: Unhandled error in
 Deferred: There are no clusters with name or ID 'tracking'
       File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1124, in _inlineCallbacks
         result = g.send(result)
       File "/usr/share/opscenter/jython/Lib/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py",
 line 523, in ClusterController
       File "/usr/share/opscenter/jython/Lib/site-packages/opscenterd/ClusterServices.py",
 line 181, in __getitem__
      (MainThread)
```

Agents Log

```
WARN [async-dispatch-23] 2017-03-20 17:13:45,230 Attempted to ping opscenterd on stomp but did not receive a reply in time, will retry again later.
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2017-03-20 17:13:45,230 Mar 20, 2017 5:13:45 PM org.jgroups.client.StompConnection run
SEVERE: JGRP000112: Connection closed unexpectedly:
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at org.jgroups.util.Util.readLine(Util.java:2825)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.STOMP.readFrame(STOMP.java:240)
    at org.jgroups.client.StompConnection.run(StompConnection.java:274)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


  INFO [async-dispatch-23] 2017-03-20 17:13:45,236 Starting DynamicEnvironmentComponent
  INFO [async-dispatch-23] 2017-03-20 17:13:45,512 Dynamic environment script output:  paths:
  cassandra-conf: /etc/dse//cassandra
  cassandra-log: /var/log/cassandra
  hadoop-log: /var/log/hadoop/userlogs
  spark-log: /var/log/spark
  dse-env: /etc/dse
  dse-conf: /etc/dse/
  hadoop-conf: /etc/dse/hadoop2-client
  spark-conf: /etc/dse//spark
  INFO [async-dispatch-23] 2017-03-20 17:13:45,522 Starting storage database connection.
 ERROR [async-dispatch-23] 2017-03-20 17:13:47,737 Can't connect to Cassandra (All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))), retrying soon.
  INFO [async-dispatch-23] 2017-03-20 17:13:47,738 Starting monitored database connection.
 ERROR [async-dispatch-23] 2017-03-20 17:13:49,965 Can't connect to Cassandra, authentication error, please carefully check your Auth settings, retrying soon.
  INFO [async-dispatch-23] 2017-03-20 17:13:49,967 Starting RepairComponent
  INFO [async-dispatch-23] 2017-03-20 17:13:49,970 Finished starting system.
  INFO [async-dispatch-26] 2017-03-20 17:13:59,971 Starting system.
  INFO [async-dispatch-26] 2017-03-20 17:13:59,973 Configuration change for component class opsagent.nodedetails.repair.RepairComponent: before: {:send-repair-fn #object[opsagent.nodedetails.repair.jmx$send_repair 0x76028b5c "opsagent.nodedetails.repair.jmx$send_repair@76028b5c"], :parse-notification-fn #object[opsagent.nodedetails.repair.jmx$parse_notification 0x5e84cf80 "opsagent.nodedetails.repair.jmx$parse_notification@5e84cf80"]}, after: {:send-repair-fn nil, :parse-notification-fn nil}
  INFO [async-dispatch-26] 2017-03-20 17:13:59,974 The following components have had a config change and will be rebuilt and restarted:  (:repair-component)
  INFO [async-dispatch-26] 2017-03-20 17:13:59,975 The component restart for  (:repair-component)  when accounting for dependencies requires these components to be restarted  #{:repair-component :http-server}
  INFO [async-dispatch-26] 2017-03-20 17:13:59,976 Stopping RepairComponent.
  INFO [async-dispatch-26] 2017-03-20 17:13:59,977 Starting StompComponent
  INFO [async-dispatch-26] 2017-03-20 17:13:59,978 SSL communication is disabled
  INFO [async-dispatch-26] 2017-03-20 17:13:59,978 Creating stomp connection to 192.168.136.250:61620
 ERROR [async-dispatch-26] 2017-03-20 17:13:59,980 Mar 20, 2017 5:13:59 PM org.jgroups.client.StompConnection connect
INFO: Connected to 192.168.136.250:61620
```

I am not able to understand whats wrong with Agent and OpsCentre?

Comment: What is in the cluster_name.conf file and the address.yaml files?

Comment: I resolved it by setting every thing from scratch.

Comment: Again I am facing same issue again. After restarting of Opscenter I am not able to connect. I have also deleted these existing cluster and trying to add from scratch but now getting error
1) Create new Cluster
Another tab was opened for OpsCenter's Lifecycle Manager. If you've closed the other tab or can't find it, you can always re-open Lifecycle Manager.
Once you create a new cluster, reload this page to continue using OpsCenter to monitor the cluster.

2) Unable to connect to cluster. Error is: Authentication error on host /192.168.147.23:9042: Failed to login. Please re-try.

Comment: go to one of the nodes and execute the following "nodetool status" and then on each node execute "netstat -tln" and post the output of  those commands. Also post the address.yaml contents.